# Snakemake: expanding only a subset of wildcards

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I can't find the solution for this probably easy problem:

I have this snakefile, which first produces the following files:

- data/sample1_P1.txt
- data/sample1_P2.txt
- data/sample2_P1.txt
- data/sample2_P2.txt

In the next step, it just concatenates the files to one file `concatenated/concatenated.txt`.

This is the minimal, reproducible example:

```
pairs = {"P1" : "P1", "P2" : "P2"}

samples = {
    "sample1": "sample1",
    "sample2": "sample2"
}

rule all:
    input: "concatenated/concatenated.txt"

rule get_txt_files:
    output:
        "data/{sample}_{pair}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo 1 > {output}
        """

rule concatenate:
  input:
    expand("data/{sample}_{pair}.txt", sample=samples, \
        pair=pairs)
  output:
    "concatenated/concatenated.txt"
  shell:
    "cat {input} > {output};"
```

My question is simple: How can I modify the rule `concatenate`, so that it concatenates the files with the same sample name?

Desired output would be:

- concatenated/sample1.txt
- concatenated/sample2.txt

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have a very similar follow-up question, so I don't think it's necessary to open a new question again:

What if my expected output would be as follows:

- data/sample1/sample1_P1
- data/sample1/sample1_P2
- data/sample2/sample2_P1
- data/sample2/sample2_P2

To be clear: I only want to create a new direcotry and move the files into that bespoke direcoty.

It seemed intuitive to do it like this:

```
pairs = {"P1" : "P1", "P2" : "P2"}

samples = {
    "sample1": "sample1",
    "sample2": "sample2"
}

rule all:
    input: expand("data/{sample}/{sample}_{pair}.txt", sample=samples, pair = pairs)

rule get_txt_files:
    output:
        "data/{sample}_{pair}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo 1 > {output}
        """

rule reorganise:
  input:
    expand("data/{{sample}}_{pair}.txt", \
        pair=pairs)
  output:
    "data/{sample}/{sample}_{pair}.txt"
  shell:
    "mv {input} data/{wildcards.sample}/.;"
```

Can you spot the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You must describe your problem: what output do you get? what did you hope or expect? And create a new question please :)

Comment: I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726969/snakemake-use-of-wildcards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rule concatenate:
  input:
    expand("data/{{sample}}_{pair}.txt", pair=pairs)
  output:
    "concatenated/{sample}.txt"
  shell:
    "cat {input} > {output};"
```

Answer to q in comment:

```
from snakemake.io import expand # automatically imported in Snakemake 

expand("data/{{sample}}_{pair}.txt", pair="A B C".split())
# ['data/{sample}_A.txt', 'data/{sample}_B.txt', 'data/{sample}_C.txt']
```

Comment: `rule all:
    input: expand("concatenated/{sample}.txt", sample=samples)`

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of the `{{}}` notation. Does this basically have the function that it is not parsed in the immediate environment (i.e. the expand function here)?

Comment: No problem; It is regular Python for avoiding formatting: `"{{hi}}_{hi}".format(hi="hei")` becomes "{hi}_hei".

Comment: I have updated my question again. I am a bit confused by how snakemake uses wildcards. I would appreciate your help on the second problem.