# snakemake: AmbiguousRuleException

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to complete a simple pipeline in snakemake, but I can't figure out how to use the wildcards correctly.

I have a folder `data` with the following files:

- `data/sample1_P1.txt`
- `data/sample1_P2.txt`
- `data/sample2_P1.txt`
- `data/sample2_P2.txt`

The wildcars in this exapmle are `sampleX` and `PX`. What I want to achieve is to first move the files into the folders `sample1` and `sample2`.

Desired output of this step:

- `data/sample1/sample1_P1.txt`
- `data/sample1/sample1_P2.txt`
- `data/sample2/sample2_P1.txt`
- `data/sample2/sample2_P2.txt`

In the next step, I want to concatenate the files inside the folders, producing the files:

- `data/sample1/sample1_concatenated.txt`
- `data/sample2/sample2_concatenated.txt`

This is what I tried:

```
pairs = {"P1" : "P1", "P2" : "P2"}

samples = {
    "sample1": "sample1",
    "sample2": "sample2"
}

rule all:
    input: expand("data/{sample}/{sample}_concatenated.txt", sample = samples)

rule get_txt_files:
    output:
        "data/{sample}_{pair}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo 1 > {output}
        """

rule reorganise:
  input:
    expand("data/{{sample}}_{pair}.txt", \
        pair=pairs)
  output:
    "data/{sample}/{sample}_{pair}.txt"
  shell:
    "mv {input} data/{wildcards.sample}/."

rule concat:
    input:
        expand("data/{{sample}}/{{sample}}_{pair}.txt", \
            pair=pairs)
    output:
        "data/{sample}/{sample}_concatenated.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

I get an error message `AmbiguousRuleException` and I can't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your workflow:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    pair = "|".join(pairs),
    sample = "|".join(samples),
```

Like the error message tells you, Snakemake finds a way to produce the output from two different rules:

```
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules reorganise and get_txt_files are ambiguous for the file data/sample1/sample1_concatenated.txt.
Consider starting rule output with a unique prefix, constrain your wildcards, or use the ruleorder directive.
Wildcards:
    reorganise: pair=concatenated,sample=sample1
    get_txt_files: pair=concatenated,sample=sample1/sample1
Expected input files:
    reorganise: data/sample1_P1.txt data/sample1_P2.txt
    get_txt_files: Expected output files:
    reorganise: data/sample1/sample1_concatenated.txt
    get_txt_files: data/sample1/sample1_concatenated.txt
```

By constraining the wildcards, you avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the wildcard ambiguity. There is one minor thing that still doesn't worK: the bash `mv` command fails, because snakemake uses bash in strict mode. The code runs well if I use `cp` instead. However, this is obviously suboptimal if large files need to be reorganised. Do you have an idea how to solve this? Either in a "Pythonian" way, or using the shell.

Comment: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#my-shell-command-fails-with-exit-code-0-from-within-a-pipe-what-s-wrong

Comment: Hope this helps; I actually do not know the answer. Does it work with `from snakemake import shell; shell.executable("bash")`?

Comment: Symlinking instead of moving is even better IMO. Snakemake might be confused by dependencies not existing anymore.

Comment: It didn't work. But thanks anyways. I will use a workaround.

Comment: @MKR Sorry to hear that. Feel free to ping me if answers to Snakemake qs are slow to come.